# Android PrintAttributes setMinMargins() not working for WebView printing

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I am using `PrintManager` to print the `WebView` and it is working properly but the issue is I want to leave whitespace at the start of every page but it is not working I have used `setMinMargins(new PrintAttributes.Margins(0, 5000, 0, 0))` but of no use.

**Below is my source code :**

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        createWebPrintJob(view);
    }
});

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument,
            "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("");
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
    }

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";

    PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
            setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME).
            setMinMargins(new PrintAttributes.Margins(0, 5000, 0, 0)).
            build();

    PrintJob printjob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            printAttrs);
}
```